# C program to calculate CRC

Tags: c++, c, crc, redundancy, cyclic

Goodnight everyone, I´ve been working on this code based on the logic that to obtain a CRC you need to do 2 XOR operations, the first one: result = data ^ generator, then it moves >> bit by bit over the 16 bits and does the XOR over and over again so the crc final is = result ^ generator until it analyzes the whole 32 bit sequence. Generator was a polynome provided by my teacher.

So far this is the code:

```
{

int dato;       // 16 bits
int polin;      // generador
double r1;      // resultado de la trama de 32 bits


dato = 0x0000000001000100;      
polin = 0x82086DB;     
r1 = dato ^ polin;     // XOR
polin >>= 1;

  while(r1 > 0){
  r1 = dato ^ polin;
  r1 = 0x1 >> dato; 
  }
 printf("%x %x",dato,polin);
 printf("\n\r CRC es: ", r1);
 getch();   
}
```

My problem is that when I try to execute it, it stays inside the "while" and doesn't provide any result, hope someone can help me.

Comment: The code looks very wrong by itself - trying to bit-shift a `double`, writing to `r1` twice in a loop discarding the previous assignment, and so on. Try to start over from scratch.

Comment: @DanielKO: To be fair the double is never bit-shifted, but I agree with all your other comments :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter sorry, I meant to write "bit-shifting **into** a double".

Comment: There is plenty of code for this on the net, including a much more efficient table-driven version. Take a look around.

Comment: Thanks guys I could solve my problem by adding  dato = r1; at the end of the iterations, and now it goes out the loop and drops a crc value of 0. Now I can continue correcting my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(r1 > 0){
   r1 = dato ^ polin;
   r1 = 0x1 >> dato; 
}
```

Your while loop never exits because the value of `r1` never changes after the first iteration. The result of the first line is never used and the second line returns the same result every time because the loop doesn't modify the value of `dato`.

Comment: Thank you very much now I can continue correcting my code. 
Now its dropping a result of 0 for each value.